# How to add $ symbol to BigDecimal types

Tags: java, symbols, bigdecimal

How to prefix a `$` symbol for a `Bigdecimal` type?
I have a response object to which I am populating the values. While setting those values I have to set a value of type `BigDecimal` and in response I need to get a `$` symbol before this value.

Answer (score 4):

Read up on [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html), which can be used to format currency amounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Test {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("$ #.00");
            double myNumber = 1234.568;
            System.out.print(" -> " + decimalFormat.format(myNumber));
        }
    }
```

Optionally more details on the class can ne fond [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)